# Average Fomula Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to find the average price contained in a column and want the formula to take into account various different sized tables, so i have incorporated a cell count in there.
My code is as follows:

Sub Average()

```
lMaxRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).Row
Range("O" & lMaxRows).Formula = "=AVERAGE(O16: O & lMaxRows - 2)"
```

End Sub

I am unsure of how the "" go in the formula itself as any way i seem to try brings up an error. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula would be:

```
"=AVERAGE(O16:O" & lMaxRows - 2 & ")"
```

Comment: Thank you! i will remember that now as no doubt will need it again soon!

Comment: @Crane92 please mark as correct. By clicking on the green check mark by the answer.  It is something only you can do.  It will mark the question as answered.